# mysql join by 2 ways - how it works? - which gives performance difference

Tags: mysql, join, explain

I had 2 different ways to query the content which showed performance difference when executed. The 1st way is

```
EXPLAIN select SOME_COLUMNS
from
( select *
  from A
  where CONDITION
) p
inner join
( select *
  from B
)st
on p.id = st.id;
```

and the output of this query returned:

```
"id"   "select_type"   "table"    "type"   "possible_keys"   "key"    "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"   "Extra"

 1       PRIMARY     derived3  ALL       NULL                 NULL    NULL    NULL      25607     "   "
 1        PRIMARY    derived2  ALL        NULL                NULL     NULL    NULL      21037   Using where; Using join buffer
 3        DERIVED             A    ALL          NULL               NULL      NULL    NULL      23202    "   "
 2        DERIVED             B    ref        IDX_A_TYPE_ID   IDX_A_ID  98      "   "        12411  Using where
```

The other way is

```
EXPALIN SELECT SOME_COLUMNS
FROM A p, B s
WHERE p.id = s.id
AND p.CONDITION;
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
id       select_type       table       type       possible_keys       key     key_len    ref     rows   Extra
 1       SIMPLE           p            ref       PRIMARY,IDX_A_TYPE_ID      IDX_A_TYPE_ID    98    const    12411    Using where
 1      SIMPLE            s           ref             PRIMARY       PRIMARY     4   local_db.p.entity_id    1
```

Why is there such a difference in the query execution plan between the 2 and number of rows being fetched in each step of query execution is more in the 1st approach? Please explain it.

Comment: In my opinion, this question would be more appropriate at [dba.se]. Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a differences because:

1. In first query doing the following:

   - create temp table with data from `A` filtering out by `CONDITION`
   - create temp table with data from `B`
   - for each row in `temp_A` we traverse `temp_B`. In this case `temp_A` using FULL SCAN, `temp_B` access by index
2. Second query

   - For each row from `A` which fall under `CONDITION` we join with table `B`.

As you can see in second query there are "preloading" data into tables and scan works in different way.

Answer (score 1):

The execution performance differs because:

- In the first case, when any inner table gets created, it is created without any index unless we specify a column name in the `WHERE` condition. So the tables `temp_A` and `temp_B` get created with the variable in the `WHERE` condition being taken as an index key. Though if we give index-id in the WHERE condition, it takes time to create that temp table with the index value.
- In the second case, the join on the 2 tables which are already created based on the index value does not need those pre-processing which happened in the first query.